# Calculate Statistical Metrics On Time-Series Data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, time-series

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        ID          DATE       QTD
0       71896517    2020-07-25  1
1       71896517    2020-09-14  2
2       72837949    2020-09-21  1
3       72848188    2020-11-03  1
4       73307986    2020-11-04  1
5       72848188    2020-11-16  1
6       71896517    2020-11-22  1
7       73307986    2020-11-25  1
8       73307986    2021-01-04  1
9       73307986    2021-02-04  1
10      72848188    2021-02-07  1
11      72837949    2021-02-11  1
```

I want to add a column to the dataframe for the monthly mean of the `QTD` column.
This metrics should be calculated for each `ID` individually (so every `ID` has its own values) and should incremement as the dataframe grows in `DATE` (which is the year-month-day).
If the `ID` doesn't have activity in a certain month, I want that month to still be included on the calculated metrics.

I want the end dataframe to look like this:

```
        ID          DATE       QTD    MEAN
0       71896517    2020-07-25  1     1.0
1       71896517    2020-09-14  2     1.0
2       72837949    2020-09-21  1     1.0
3       72848188    2020-11-03  1     1.0
4       73307986    2020-11-04  1     1.0
5       72848188    2020-11-16  1     2.0
6       71896517    2020-11-22  1     0.8
7       73307986    2020-11-25  1     2.0
8       73307986    2021-01-04  1     1.0
9       73307986    2021-02-04  1     1.0
10      72848188    2021-02-07  1     0.75
11      72837949    2021-02-11  1     0.33
```

How can I go about to implement this?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Almost any PANDAS tutorial includes `groupby` and `mean` examples.

Comment: But you only start counting statistics from the first month where an ID appears?  This can be done iteratively, but there's certainly no built-in pandas function to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's usually an iterative solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def monthdelta(a,b):
    a1,a2,a3 = (int(k) for k in a.split('-'))
    b1,b2,b3 = (int(k) for k in b.split('-'))
    return (a1*12+a2) - (b1*12+b2)

data = [
[ 71896517, "2020-07-25", 1 ],
[ 71896517, "2020-09-14", 2 ],
[ 72837949, "2020-09-21", 1 ],
[ 72848188, "2020-11-03", 1 ],
[ 73307986, "2020-11-04", 1 ],
[ 72848188, "2020-11-16", 1 ],
[ 71896517, "2020-11-22", 1 ],
[ 73307986, "2020-11-25", 1 ],
[ 73307986, "2021-01-04", 1 ],
[ 73307986, "2021-02-04", 1 ],
[ 72848188, "2021-02-07", 1 ],
[ 72837949, "2021-02-11", 1 ],
]

df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=["ID", "DATE", "QTD"] )

startdate = {}
sums = {}
sumsqs = {}
num = {}
stdev = []
means = []

for row in df.T.iteritems():
    id = row[1]['ID']
    if id not in startdate:
        num[id] = 1
        startdate[id] = row[1]['DATE']
        sums[id] = row[1]['QTD']
        sumsqs[id] = row[1]['QTD'] * row[1]['QTD']
        means.append( row[1]['QTD'] )
        stdev.append( 0 )
    else:
        num[id] += 1
        sums[id] += row[1]['QTD']
        sumsqs[id] += row[1]['QTD'] * row[1]['QTD']
        delta = monthdelta(row[1]['DATE'],startdate[id]) + 1
        means.append( sums[id] / delta )
        if delta == 1:
            stdev.append( 0 )
        else:
            stdev.append( np.sqrt((delta*sumsqs[id] - sums[id]*sums[id])/delta))

print( means )
df['MEAN'] = pd.Series(means)
print( stdev )
df['STDEV'] = pd.Series(stdev)
print( df )
```

Output:

```
[1, 1.0, 1, 1, 1, 2.0, 0.8, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.75, 0.3333333333333333]
[0, 1.4142135623730951, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.6733200530681511, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8660254037844386, 1.1547005383792515]
          ID        DATE  QTD      MEAN     STDEV
0   71896517  2020-07-25    1  1.000000  0.000000
1   71896517  2020-09-14    2  1.000000  1.414214
2   72837949  2020-09-21    1  1.000000  0.000000
3   72848188  2020-11-03    1  1.000000  0.000000
4   73307986  2020-11-04    1  1.000000  0.000000
5   72848188  2020-11-16    1  2.000000  0.000000
6   71896517  2020-11-22    1  0.800000  1.673320
7   73307986  2020-11-25    1  2.000000  0.000000
8   73307986  2021-01-04    1  1.000000  0.000000
9   73307986  2021-02-04    1  1.000000  0.000000
10  72848188  2021-02-07    1  0.750000  0.866025
11  72837949  2021-02-11    1  0.333333  1.154701
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That works great! I am trying to be build upon your answer to get the standard deviation. So far I got this: `std.append( np.sqrt( ( row[1]['QTD'] - ( sums[id] / (delta+1) ) )**2/sums[id] ) )` . I am not sure it is enterely correct though. My doubt is on the sum the formula has and implementing that on this code. Can you verify if that is right?
I do this inside the `else` only and then I add it to the df.

Comment: I'm not sure an incremental std dev is very meaningful.  You can do that by tracking both the sums and the sum of squares, and the number of samples, then doing `sqrt( (num[id] * sumsqs[id] - sum[id] * sum[id]) / num[id])`.

Comment: Not sure why but when I try to run the loop in a dataframe that I read from a csv I get all NaN values on the calculated metrics. Is this because of the append? How can I correct that?

Comment: Did you print the columns before appending?  Note that I did that in my example, just to be sure.  NaNs can come from dividing by zero.  If you borrowed my std dev code, did you remember to bump num[id] in each loop?

Comment: I maintained the prints and there the results are correct. When the dataframe is displayed, on the calculated columns there are only NaN. This is strange. If you can edit the answer with the solution would be great. In reality I read from a csv and would like to implement the loop to it.

Comment: Actually, standard deviation doesn't work like this.  We can compute standard deviation for all of the individual samples, or we can compute standard deviation by month, but to do that, we have to treat the sums for a month as a single sample.  I'll see if that can be done easily

Comment: Doing stdev by sample makes more sense, but in that case the stdev is 0 for all except 71896517, because the quantity is always 1.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I got it working with my dataframe!

Comment: I am applying the provided code to a big data set and I get some wrong values for certain `IDs`. Is this a problem, like a flaw or something, from the code? For the most part it is right but then there are some clients that have one entry and their mean and other features is incorrect. Not sure that it is because the data is put into a series and then added to the df. Is there a way to achieve the same with the df manipulation with `.loc` and `.iloc` for example?